# Setting the beamer titleframe font family to roman

Tags: beamer

I am creating a beamer presentation, and would like to have my titleframe using the *roman* font family.

How do we change *just one frame*?

This may sound trivial to some of you but here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

% This here doesn't change anything:
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\rmfamily\selectfont}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\title{Awesome}
\author{Me \textsc{Myself}}
\date{\today}
\institute{Lab}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage

\vfill

\begin{center}
Supervision: Dr. Hyde
\end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Trying to put the frame content in `{\rmfamily ...}` does not seem the right solution either: I think you cannot put several paragraphs like this in brackets (?).

As a side question, more generally, I often need commands that should be used like this: `{\small ...}` for example, but an environment would be more appropriate. Isn't there a direct conversion from simple commands (`\small`, `\sffamily`, ...) to environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frametitle` has nothing to do with the titlepage, thats what you get as "headline" on slides when you use `\frametitle{...}`. To modify the font of the titlepage, you have to adjust the components, such as `author` or `date` separately.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

% This here doesn't change anything:
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\rmfamily\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{author}{family=\rmfamily\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{family=\rmfamily\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{date}{family=\rmfamily\selectfont}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\title{Awesome}
\author{Me \textsc{Myself}}
\date{\today}
\institute{Lab}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage

\vfill

\begin{center}
    \usebeamerfont{author}Supervision: Dr. Hyde
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\frame{normal text}


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As for the side question, you can probably define your own commands, but please do not complain when (not if) they will break something:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mysmall}[1]{\begingroup\tiny #1\endgroup}

\begin{document}
normal

\mysmall{small}

normal

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: aah, thanks also for the second question ! =)